# strong reference to delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I read somewhere that if i have delegates in my app, i should keep a weak reference to them
however, when i debug the app, the app doesnt want to move on, when i call on a delegate
because my delegate has already been deallocated by the time it reached that method

why ?

If i put the reference to be "strong" everything works just fine, though i am not sure what are the consequences of that on my memory allocations and the fact that those delegates are not in "sharedInstance" classes....

code:

```
    @interface LoginProcessListener()
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<UserSettingsDelegate>userSettings;
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<DisclaimerDelegate>disclaimerDelegate;
@end

@implementation LoginProcessListener


-(instancetype)initWithUserSettings:(id<UserSettingsDelegate>)userSettings andDisclaimerDelegate:(id<DisclaimerDelegate>)disclaimerDelegate{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        [self setUserSettings:userSettings];
        [self setDisclaimerDelegate:disclaimerDelegate];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)onLoginAuthenticationProcessFinished{
    User *user = [_userSettings getUserDetails];
    if(user && [_disclaimerDelegate isConfirmedDisclaimer:[user disclaimerInfo]]){
        [_disclaimerDelegate confirmedDisclaimer];
    }else {
        [_disclaimerDelegate needDisplayDisclaimer];
    }
}

-(void)onLoggedInUserDetailsReceived:(User *)user{
    [_userSettings saveUserDetails:user];  <== here my _userSettings is already nil;
}
```

Comment: delegate should always be weak, you should have design patterns in such a way , delegate will be weak and your app runs perfectly. post some code related .

Comment: with strong defined delegates you easily get reference cycles and objects won't dealloc. If your delegate deallocs too early, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Volker added code, where is my problem ?

Comment: The problem is that your user settings provider went out of existence. You must ask yourself how that happened. (However, one might argue that the user settings provider is not really a delegate and that a strong reference is correct here.)

Comment: @LenaBru for one thing if you declare properties, use them via `self.propertyName`and not with `_propertyName`. if you delegate is dealloced too early, than this happens because the object is not held in a strong reference outside your posted class. Yet, your userSettings probably should be declared strong.

Answer (score 1):

> when i debug the app, the app doesnt want to move on, when i call on a delegate because my delegate has already been deallocated by the time it reached that method

But that is your bug, which you must track down. The whole point of a delegate is that you must not permit it to die before the thing whose delegate it is. In general, if a delegate dies before the other thing does, you are doing something wrong; it is the job of a delegate to live as long as it is needed.

On the other hand (there is always an "other hand") it may be that what you are calling a delegate is not really a delegate. It is a delegate more or less if it is an object with a primary existence of its own. If it's just a packet of values or a purely ancillary object whose only purpose is in connection with the object keeping a reference to it, then it is not a delegate and a strong reference is correct.

Comment: how do i know where it dies?

Comment: i put a log in its dealloc method , andit didnt dealloc, but that is possibly because i've overriden the dealloc method, and didnt call to super, and it wont let me call to super, because i am using ARC

Comment: If it didn't dealloc it didn't die. If it didn't die your question makes no sense. Make sure this is the right UserSettingsDelegate object. If it is, and it really isn't dealloc-ing, then something else must be setting your `userSettings` to nil.

Comment: perfect answer & explanation of delegate. lena, you should following this link[link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html to  make your understanding towards delegate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yours architecture is wrong. It's should be:

```
@interface UserSettings
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<UserSettingsDelegate>userSettingsDelegate;
@end

@interface Disclaimer
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<DisclaimerDelegate>disclaimerDelegate;
@end
```

Actually yours userSettings not real delegate, it just member of LoginProcessListener, so you may use strong references.

Commonly `id<UserSettingsDelegate>` creates `UserSettings` and own reference on it. If `UserSettings` will own reference at `id<UserSettingsDelegate`, then there will be retain loop.

Comment: this is wrong, because this is not what i meant to do. i meant to create class UserSettings that implements the UserSettingsDelegate protocol, and class Disclaimer that implements DisclaimerDelegate protocol, and wherever i need the implementation of settings and disclaimer, i pass in the delegates, rather than the actual classes, this way, when i change the implementation, only 1 class is affected, and not 3

Comment: @LenaBru, so as I said before, yours userSettings and disclaimerDelegate isn't delegates. It's just pointers at protocols.

Answer (score 0):

> when i debug the app, the app doesnt want to move on, when i call on a
>   delegate because my delegate has already been deallocated by the time
>   it reached that method

What's your seeking is how a weakly defined property behaves.

Via the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30)

> Because a weak reference doesn’t keep an object alive, it’s possible for the referenced
>   object to be deallocated while the reference is still in use. To avoid a dangerous 
>   dangling pointer to the memory originally occupied by the now deallocated object, a weak 
>   reference is automatically set to nil when its object is deallocated.

*Simply put, if the delegate is no longer allocated, it's being released elsewhere.*

With that said, your bug is likely not there at all, but elsewhere.  You're going to have to backtrace `_userSession` to verify where it's being created and what objects have strong references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a strong reference to a delegate is permissible, but you need to understand what is going on as it has risks that you should be aware of.

Apple's documentation kind of glosses over this, just saying that delegate users keep a weak link to the delegate, and in general this is true, but there are cases, and yours may be one of them, where it makes sense to keep a strong reference.  In general, this happens in asynchronous code where the delegate might otherwise be released before it is used.

Too much hand waving: here is a concrete example.  NSURLConnection needs a delegate to do asynchronous IO.  In order to make this reliable and to greatly simplify it's usage, NSURLConnection keeps a strong reference to it's delegate as long as it needs one.  Here is a quote from the NSURLConnection documentation :-

"Note: During a request, the connection maintains a strong reference to its delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled"

In simple terms, under ARC, "releases that strong reference" probably means setting the property to nil.

Summary: If you know what you're doing, use strong references when you have to, and document well so that the next person to see that code understands why you did it.

Comment: It probably mantains strong reference to delegate using objc_setAssociatedObject, while delegate property is still weak

Answer (score 0):

You can temoprarily make a strong reference to the delegate object, which is excatly what NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol does. I do it like this:

Let's say i have a protocol for downloading images.

```
@implementation AsyncImageLoadManager <NSURLConnectionDelegate>

static char delegateStrongReferenceKey;
.......
-(void)startDownload {
    ....
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &delegateStrongRefernceKey, _delegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    _imageConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &delegateStrongRefernceKey, _delegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    _downloadTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ //I use tihs instead of [connection start]; so that download continues if app goes to background
        [_imageConnection cancel];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_downloadTaskID];
        _downloadTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &delegateStrongRefernceKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
    }];

}

..../// and in connectionDidFinishLoading and connectionDidFailWithError you release the strong reference with:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_downloadTaskID];
_downloadTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &delegateStrongRefernceKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
```